# How to optimize SQL Server stored procedure with Levenstein algorithm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This procedure takes about minute with 10k rows.

How to make it faster?

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
         idl int,
         idr int,
         prof decimal(10,2),
         sportkind nvarchar(50),
         eventtype nvarchar(100), 
         eventname nvarchar(100),
         eventdate datetime,
         iscorridore bit
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
   SELECT 
      l.Id, r.Id, 
      (100.0 / (1.0 / l.CoeffValue + 1.0 / r.CoeffValue) - 100.0), 
      r.SportKind, r.CoeffType, r.Team1 + '-' + r.Team2, r.EventDate, 
      dbo.CheckForCorridor(l.CoeffParam, l.CoeffKind, r.CoeffParam, r.CoeffKind)
   FROM
      Lines l, Lines r
   WHERE
      --l.BookmakerName != r.BookmakerName AND
      l.EventDate = r.EventDate
      AND l.SportKind = r.SportKind 
      AND (l.CoeffType = r.CoeffType OR (l.CoeffType is null AND r.CoeffType is null)) 
      AND dbo.CheckForFork(l.CoeffValue, r.CoeffValue) = 1
      AND ((dbo.Levenstein(l.Team1, r.Team1) > 0.8
            AND dbo.Levenstein(l.Team2, r.Team2) > 0.8)   
           OR (dbo.Levenstein(l.Team1, r.Team2) < 0.3
               OR dbo.Levenstein(l.Team2, r.Team1) < 0.3)
          ) 
      AND dbo.CheckSimpleCoeff(l.CoeffParam, l.CoeffKind, r.CoeffParam, r.CoeffKind) = 1

INSERT INTO Forks (Name, Profit, EventDate, [Event], SportKind, EventType, LeftLine_Id, RightLine_Id, IsCorridore)
   --поменять eventname
   SELECT 
       eventname, prof, eventdate, eventname, sportkind, eventtype, 
       idl, idr, iscorridore  
   FROM 
       #TempTable temp
   WHERE   
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Forks c
                   WHERE temp.idl = c.LeftLine_Id 
                     AND temp.idr = c.RightLine_Id)

   DROP TABLE #TempTable
END
```

Levenstein is CLR functions from Simmetrics.

I try to find a pair of rows which fit the rules above in procedure, and then create new entries and write them to another table.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: One why are you even calculating Levenstein on rows you are not going to use.  In the very end you have not exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Optimizing the Levenshtein algorithm is hard.  One method is to pre-filter the results before applying the algorithm.  In SQL, you can do this by creating a new table with one row per name and letter and then doing a join.  For instance, if you want names that have at least three letters in common, then:

```
select nl.name, nl2.name
from nameletters nl join
     nameletters nl2
     on nl.char = nl2.char and nl.name <> nl2.name
group by nl.name, nl2.name
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Or, similarly, consider the Levenshtein distance only for the 100 names that have the most letters in common:

```
select *
from (select nl.name, nl2.name, rank(count(*)) over (partition by nl.name) as rnk
      from nameletters nl join
           nameletters nl2
           on nl.char = nl2.char and nl.name <> nl2.name
      group by nl.name, nl2.name
      having count(*) >= 3
     ) nn
having rnk >= 100;
```

These are heuristic approaches, but they might help for your problem.

Comment: I need to compare each entry with each in source table, Levenstein is one of parameters. How i can choose 100 names with common letters?

Comment: @user2642119 . . . That is what the last query does, assuming you have a table with one row per name and letter.